# problema simpels com Vetor e Structs

Tags: c, array

Olá, gostaria de saber porque não tá indo, já procurei em muito locais mas não conseguir achar

em C

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct ficha_pessoal{
    int idade;
    char sexo;
    int CPF [11];
    int CPFc [3];
    float salario;
    char nome [40];
} FICHA;
int main(){
    FICHA x;
    x.idade=32;
    x.sexo = 'M';
    x.nome[40]= "JOSE DA SILVA";
    x.salario =850;
    x.CPF[1] = {5,3,1,9,8,7,0,0,,1,4,1};
    printf("%d",x.CPF[1]);
return 0;
}
```

diz isso no erro

> ||In function 'main':|
>   |18|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
>   |20|error: expected expression before '{' token|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Verifique se o valor que você está passando para o CPF está correto.

Comment: `"JOSE DA SILVA"` é do tipo `const char *`, e `x.nome` é do tipo `char []`. Lembre sempre que arrays e ponteiros são tipos bem diferentes. Para copiar uma string para um array use `strncpy()`. Neste caso faça: `strncpy(x.nome, "JOSE DA SILVA", 40);` e faça o `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Desse modo que você está fazendo a atribuição, só é possível na declaração da variável. (ou se fizeres uma function para isso).

O primeiro erro é porque você não consegue atribuir um valor desse modo na linguagem C.

O segundo erro é de sintaxe, mostrando que '{}'(chaves) não existem na atribuição de um tipo desse (inteiro).

Espero ter ajudado.

Dê uma olhada melhor nesse link aqui: `https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Vetores`

Abraço e bons estudos!

Answer (score 0):

Como foi dito acima, o modo de atribuição `variável = [valores]`, em C, só pode ser utilizado na declaração da variável.

Outro ponto importante é que mesmo que você não tivesse usado `{}` e sim `[]` **E** a linguagem permitisse a atribuição de valor dessa forma, ainda estaria incorreto.
Ao fazer `x.CPF[1] = [valores,aqui]` - Você está tentando atribuir um array inteiro a uma única casa de um array.